# Renaming Family when people have not thought of others as part of their Family?

Tags: terminology

Some (most) Family Tree software uses the term Family regularly in reports and display. An example is Family Historian with Family Work Sheet and Family of Individual.

I have people who are not happy with the term Family for some of their situation.

One person has never lived with the mother of their child and had only met her once. While he now sees the child regularly, he does not see them as part of his Family.

Another has had no contact with their child and while acknowledging her as his, has never considered her a part of his Family.

They (and others) have indicated they prefer some other term than Family on those reports.

I have looked at Dictionaries and Thesaurus and done internet search on several terms but have found no options.

Excluding how I would make those changes, I am seeking possible terms to use in lieu of Family.

Comment: Rather than label something "Family of X" - why not just label it as "X"? Or "X and descendents"? I don't think that there is a synonym for Family that isn't loaded in some way. I also think that people can recognize a chart for what it is without a label.

Comment: I have come across this situation before.  The term used then was "Relations of X" (chosen as a more neutral term since people can be 'related' by blood or by marriage).